# Copy a portion of template from one component to another component in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-components, ng-template

Basically, i have something like this in template of component 1.

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and this in template of component 2 which is a sibling of component1

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>component 2</h1>
</div>
```

What i want is when a particular variable in component 2 ,say, `"toggled" = true`, the template of component 2 should look like this

```html
<div class="test">
   <h1>component 2</h1>
   <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am using angular version 4.0.0 . I read about templateoutlet, but could not figure out how to share it across different components. Is there any way to copy template fragment from one component and use it in another component?

Comment: you can also make use of even emitter and when toggled get all value of required to make template 1 from service or via emitters

Comment: How to refer to a specific fragment of code in template 1 from component 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-template`

```
Injectable()
export class TemplatePasser{
    template;

}
```

the component with template :

```
@Component({
  selector:'custom'
  template:`

     <ng-template #template>
         <div class="test">
          <h1>component 2</h1>
        </div>
       </ng-template>  


`
})
export class CustomComponent{

   constructor(private templatePasser:TemplatePasser){


   }
   @ViewChild('template') templateRef:TemplateRef
   ngAfterViewInit(){
       this.templatePasser.template =template;
    }
}


and then the other one that is using that template : 



@Component({
  selector:'the-other-custom'
  template:`

   <div *ngIf="template" class="test" style="border:1px solid red">
       <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></div>
       <ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
       </ul>
    </div>  


`
})
export class CustomComponent{

   constructor(private templatePasser:TemplatePasser){}
   template
   ngAfterViewInit(){
       this.template = this.templatePasser.template;
    }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Er9Vx4qtJwc69IAQYjgD?p=preview

Comment: both the templates are in different components

Comment: you can pass the template ref around with a service

Comment: With your solution, when i log this.template in 'the-other-custom' component, it is printing the correct portion of template. But, while adding `[ngTemplateOutlet]="template"`  to the HTML, it is creating error "templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function". Any solution for this?

Comment: have you checked my Plunker?

Comment: Yeah... plunker works fine. Also, when i try `[ngTemplateOutlet]="template"` with "template" being a code fragment in same html, it still works. The issue occurs when "template" is something that is defined from it's component.ts file. Is it any issue with datatype? I have declared "template" as `template:TemplateRef<any>;` in component.ts